# Numba JIT changing results if values are printed

Tags: python, numpy, jit, numba

I started working with numba today, mainly because I have a nested for-loop that can take quite a while with regular python code.

I have a macports version of python-2.7 with llvm-3.6 and the pip version of numba (everything is up-to-date)

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import pandas as pd
from numba import jit
from numpy import nan, full

@jit
def movingAverage(adj_close, maxMA):
    ma = full([len(adj_close), maxMA], nan, dtype=float64)
    ind = range( 1, len(adj_close)+1 )
    for d in ind:
        m = max( 0, d-maxMA-1)
        adj = adj_close[d-1:m:-1] if (m or d==maxMA+1) else adj_close[d-1::-1]
        cs = adj.cumsum()
        for i in range( len(adj) ):
            ma[d-1][i] = ( cs[i] / (i+1) )
        print ma
    return ma
```

I'm calculating a rolling mean for the input `adj_close` for up to `maxMA` days.

`adj_close` is a array of values, one value per day

I started by creating `ma`, a holder for the values that are going to be calculated. And work out the vaules for each day individually (note that the first day can only have an average involving 1 day, the second, 2 and so on up to the maxMA)

If I input something like `adj_close = array(range(5), dtype=float64)` and `maxMA = 3` get the right answer as follows:

```
array([[  0.,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   0.5,  nan],
       [  2.,   1.5,   1.],
       [  3.,   2.5,   2.],
       [  4.,   3.5,   3.]])
```

However, If I take out the `print ma` line, just before the return of my function, it returns only part of the answer:

```
array([[ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan],
       [  3.,   2.5,   2.],
       [  4.,   3.5,   3.]])
```

Why is that happening? Why does @jit needs the print between those loops to get the answer right? What can I do to get rid of the print statement (that greatly increases the runtime)?

---

Edit: I'm accepting @JoshAdel suggestion and opened a [issue](https://github.com/numba/numba/issues/1690) at Numba's github. I'm, therefore, accepting @MSeifert answer as the workaround solved the problem for me.

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. I'd post something to the Numba issues on github since you have a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I get the right answer when I run it (Python3, and possibly a different version of Numba). However, I wonder if changing your indexing line to `ma[d-1,i] = ...` would help. I think @MSeifert is right about the python vs nopython mode, and I recall that nopython mode doesn't deal with sequential (i.e. `[a][b]`) indexing very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `numba` does something strange here but probably because of the mixture of `python` and `nopython` mode. If I use Python 3.5 the returns are identical with and without `print`.

For python 2.7 I think the problem is because the for-loop is either compiled in `nopython` mode (without print) or in `python` mode (with print). But then converted to `python` when it exits the loop. But that's just guessing. But I tried it with:

```
import pandas as pd
from numba import jit
from numpy import nan, full
import numpy as np

@jit
def movingAverage(adj_close, maxMA):
    ma = full([len(adj_close), maxMA], nan, dtype=np.float64)
    ind = range( 1, len(adj_close)+1 )
    for d in ind:
        m = max( 0, d-maxMA-1)
        adj = adj_close[d-1:m:-1] if (m or d==maxMA+1) else adj_close[d-1::-1]
        cs = adj.cumsum()
        for i in range( len(adj) ):
            ma[d-1][i] = ( cs[i] / (i+1) )
        if d == ind[-1]:
            return ma # notice that I return it after the last loop but before the loop terminates.
    #return ma
```

and it does return:

```
array([[  0.,  nan,  nan],
       [  1.,   0.5,  nan],
       [  2.,   1.5,   1.],
       [  3.,   2.5,   2.],
       [  4.,   3.5,   3.]])
```

This is however not a very effient way because of the recalculation of `len(adj_close)+1`. This could be stored somewhere.

Comment: instead of using `if d == len(adj_close) + 1:` I can use `if d == ind[-1]` to the same result without the recalculation

Comment: I have edited the answer, I don't know if such a list lookup is faster than the calculation but it looks faster, especially for small inputs.

Comment: typical values are in the order of 200.000 for `len(adj_close)` and `maxMA = 1000`. For this it takes 1min16s to run with `if d == ind[-1]` (same for storing it elsewhere) and 1min20s to run with `if d == len(adj_close) + 1`